# how to get load per cores or processor using powershell scripting?

Tags: powershell

I have written the following script for Windows Server 2012 & Windows 7 that displays load per processor by using `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor`. It is running quite well and also displays the load on console but when I keep checking the console outputs with performance monitor (% processor time), it is not matching with the console output. Is my script for checking the load per processor correct? How can I summarize my script with performance monitor?

```
while(1)
{
$cpucores = get-wmiobject win32_perfformatteddata_perfos_processor 
$currenttime = get-date | out-file report.txt -append 
write-host
write-host "CPU Cores individually usage Monitoring"
write-host  $currenttime
for ($i=0; $i -lt $cpucores.count ; $i++) 
    {
    if($i -eq $cpucores.count-1) 
    {
    #write-host 
    $value=$cpucores[$i].percentprocessortime
    write-host "Total CPU " $value"% usage" 
    write-output "Total CPU  $value % usage" >> report.txt 
    write-output "..............................................................." >> report.txt

        }
    else
        {
        $load_value=[double]$cpucores[$i].percentprocessortime
        write-host "CPU Core"$i $load_value  "% usage"  -foregroundcolor green 
        write-output "CPU Core $i   $load_value %  usage" >> report.txt

        }
  }
  start-sleep -seconds 1

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the built in `Get-Counter` cmdlet?

```
$counter = Get-Counter "\processor(*)\% processor time"
$counter.countersamples
```

I think you will have better results with this.